# Are the following codes equivalent?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C=\left\{ 10,21,02\right\}$ and $D=\left\{ 00,11,22\right\}$.

Determine whether or not the codes are similar or not. I understand that for a code to be equivalent we can take a combination of:

(I) Permutations of columns 
(II)Permutations of symbols in a fixed place

Comment: Is there any operation that will take, say, `10` to any of the elements of $D$?

Comment: Don't think so ?